# Cannot import tensorflow_quantum module in Colab

Tags: machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, programming, tfq

I was trying to install the tensor flow quantum module using the one given in their official website but it is showing these errors while installing.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-quantum (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-quantum
```

Can you please let me know how to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe Google Colab has been updated to use Python 3.10 as its default. You can check by running

```
!python --version
```

Tensorflow Quantum is only compatible with Python 3.7, 3.8, 3.9. So if you are using Python 3.10, attempting to `pip install tensorflow-quantum` will result in the `No matching distribution` error that you got.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this:

```
!wget -c https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-py39_23.5.2-0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-py39_23.5.2-0-Linux-x86_64.sh
!time bash ./Miniconda3-py39_23.5.2-0-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
```